# Using cqlsh utility in windows to access a remote cassandra serv

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

I am using a widows virtual desktop as my developer machine.  I had been using **`datastax-studio`** to access a **`common-dataStax-cassandra-cluster`** installed on remote server machines.

Apparently, not all CQL commands are supported by `datastax-studio`, for example `COPY`, `LOAD` commands etc. So I tried to install **`CQLSH utility`** on my developer machine.

Seems **`Cqlsh`** is meant to be used only on **`Linux-based platforms`** having python.
So I tried to use it within `git-bash` on my windows machine. First I unzipped the gzip file using **`git-bash`** and then got **`python`** installed on my machine.

Now when I run the **`xxxx/cqlsh-6.8.31/bin/cqlsh.sh` or `xxxx/cqlsh-6.8.31/bin/cqlsh.py`** , I get below error.
*Disclaimer- I have never worked on python.*

```
$ ./cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\apps\CASSANDRA\cqlsh-6.8.31\bin\dsecqlsh.py", line 95, in <module>
    import cqlsh  # nopep8
  File "C:\projects\apps\CASSANDRA\cqlsh-6.8.31\bin\cqlsh.py", line 151, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Question is

1. Is it even possible to run Cqlsh on a widows machine not having a complete cassandra installation ?
2. If answer to above is yes, then how to set it up ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, yes.  Which version of Python do you have installed?  These days cqlsh runs on only specific versions of Python 3; 3.6 to 3.10, I think.

*Note: There is a [breaking change in Python 3.11 for cqlsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673247/cannot-able-to-run-cqlsh-due-to-python-attribute-error)*

In any case, if you have a version of Python in that range, [you should be able to install it using Pip](https://pypi.org/project/cqlsh/) (Python's package manager).

```
pip install cqlsh
```

Pip will make sure you get all of the required dependencies, including the `six` module.

**Possible Quick Fix**

Just a parting thought, but maybe try installing six:

```
pip install six
```

Comment: The latest release of the cqlsh package on pypi.org, version 6.1.0, has a fix I wrote to support installing on Windows as an executable. The DataStax Python driver still includes python 2 support, and thus it will require 'six'.